# SSH into my Mac from my iPod

Tags: macos, iphone, ssh, tunnel

OK, so this is what I got, but it doesn't look right...

The set up is as follows:

My Mac is on a wireless network, presumably behind a firewall over which I have no administrator privileges.  Further, said wireless network changes my internal IP address randomly at random times, so I do not know what my IP address is.

Note that localhost is a variable IP address.

I forward some port or the other to my DNS:

```
ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 sourceuser@remotehost
```

Connect to my remotehost from my machine:

```
ssh sourceuser@remotehost
```

And then connect to the port I forwarded:

```
ssh localhost -p 19999
```

[solved] Second question, there are a bunch of SSH clients for the iPhone.  Which one should I use?

EDIT: Since jailbreak is not illegal, simply frowned upon by the Corporation, I've decided to go with that.  I have a nice shell with OpenSSH and the works.  Best of all, it's free and it does exactly what you expect.

Comment: no one loves me?

Comment: What is your first question? You should explain what exact problem you're having.

Comment: it's not working, and even if it did, would this approach be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is localhost a variable IP? It should be something like 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1, and be rather constant.

I prefer iSSH for the iPhone, as it includes VNC capabilities as well.

Are you trying to tether your laptop to your iPhone?

Comment: Actually, if you jailbreak you get a proper full terminal with openssh.  And apparently jailbreak is NOT illegal, so I'm fine with it, so that deals with that part of it.  I am not sure what to do with the local host, etc, which is the main reason I am asking.  The thing is, my laptop will be on a large wifi system and I will want to access it even when I'm NOT local.